# RVM installing Ruby error "File name too long"

Tags: ruby, rvm

Trying to install Ruby 2.7.0 (or other version) with RVM throws:

```
/Users/me/.rvm/tmp/rvm_src_612/defs to /Users/me/.rvm/src/ruby-2.7.0: File name too long
-bash: cd: /Users/me/.rvm/src/ruby-2.7.0: No such file or directory
Source directory is missing.
Did the download or extraction fail?
Halting the installation.
```

Tried `sudo` and `rvm reload`, same error. How do I successfully install a Ruby version with RVM?

Comment: Is this macOS? Is this the latest RVM? It seems like a bug in RVM but could be a quirk of your local system.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run:

```
rvm get head
rvm reload
rvm install 2.7.0
```

If you're using zshell with oh my zsh there could be problem with terminalapp.
Your problem looks similar to this: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/1161#issuecomment-9204859

Switch to bash terminal and try it again.

Comment: thanks, I'm on bash already (iTerm2 and Terminal), tried the above, same results :\

Comment: If the problem persists I would suggest reinstalling rvm. It's best to physically delete the `.rvm` folder first